# Nested ordered lists of different types

Tags: html

I am currently trying to nest several ordered list html tags, and have each of them as separate types. However, all of the list elements are staying as type 1, and i cannot tell why.

This is my code:

```
<ol type="1">
    <li>Sales Associate 2003- Present</li>
    <ol type="2">
        <li>Target West, Wichita, KS</li>
            <ol type="3">
                <li>Help customers with purchases</li>
                <li>Handle customer questions and complaints, working to ensure complete customer satisfaction</li>
                <li>Run cash register</li>
                <li>Monitor security system</li>
            </ol>
    </ol>

    <li>Grounds Keeper 1998-2003</li>
    <ol type="2">
        <li>Riverside Golf Course, Wichita, KS</li>
            <ol type="3">
                <li>Helped with the general outdoor maintenance of the apartment complex</li>
                <li>Worked as a member of a team</li>
                <li>Scheduled maintenance repairs with tenants as needed</li>
            </ol>
    </ol>

</ol>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't start a list within another list, it needs to be within the list item. And what are you expecting the type attribute to do here? Did you mean the start attribute?

Comment: You can not have an OL as a child of OL, that's invalid HTML. You need to put it into a list item.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an `ol` as a direct child of another `ol`, it must be nested within an `li`.

```
<ol type="1">
    <li>Sales Associate 2003- Present
       <ol type="2">
           <li>Target West, Wichita, KS
               <ol type="3">
                   <li>Help customers with purchases</li>
                   <li>Handle customer questions and complaints, working to ensure complete customer satisfaction</li>
                   <li>Run cash register</li>
                   <li>Monitor security system</li>
               </ol>
           </li>
       </ol>
   </li>
....
</ol>
```

Furthermore `type` 2 and 3 are not valid attribute values.

Valid properties are:

- `1`  Represents decimal numbers (eg. 1. 2. 3. ... etc)
- `a`  Represents lower case latin alphabet (eg. a. b. c. ... etc)
- `A`  Represents upper case latin alphabet (eg. A. B. C. ... etc)
- `i`  Represents lower case roman numerals (eg. i. ii. iii. ... etc)
- `I`  Represents upper case roman numerals (eg. I. II. III. ... etc)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your new list into a `li` element like this:

```
<li> Text
 <ol>
  <li>...</li>
 </ol>
</li>
```